# How does Chromium browser determine the default keboard layout on Linux?

Tags: debian, keyboard-layout, chrome

I'm trying to figure out how the Chromium Browser sets up the default onscreen  keyboard layout / locale on Debian (and general Linux OS as well).

Does Chromium Browser sniff the OS settings and/or ask it for locale information? Or does Chromium Browser ask the user for their preference?

I haven't found any helpful documentation specific to Chromium Browser, only some for Chromium OS. Are they similar in their implementation?

Comment: What gives you the impression that the browser knows (or cares) what the keyboard layout is? (I’m trying to understand what led to your question.)

Comment: I was under the impression that Chromium can supply an on-screen keyboard as an accessibility feature. The hardware we use does not have a keyboard; it has a touch screen so it has an on-screen keyboard. If you need to fill in a website text box on a touch screen, is that keyboard not provided by Chromium?

Comment: I don’t think Chromium has its own on-screen keyboard; there are extensions which can provide one, but I suspect yours is provided by the desktop environment.